# jQuery and BlockUI Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, blockui

I am using jQuery 1.5.1 and BlockUI 2.38 in an ASP.NET page. I try to block the UI on a button click event using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Button3").click(function () {
    $.blockUI({ message: 'Test' });
      setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
    });
});

...

<div id="globalDiv">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Width="80px" Text="Button3" />
  </form>
</div>
```

The click event is called upon clicking the button and on calling the `$.blockUI` I get back

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Is there any known bug on the two versions, or are there any other reasons why this doesn't work...

Thanks, Tobias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that the blockUI plugin script is actually being loaded?

Comment: Your comment lead me to the solution. I registered the blockUI.js file in the aspx file, but not in the custom user control ascx files, like I did with the jQuery and jQueryUI files. After registering it there as well, it worked like a charm. Thanks Matt!!